# Pasar información de un evento click que está dentro de un foreach a una variable

Tags: javascript

Quiero sacar el "indx" que genera el `foreach` para almacenarlo en una variable y ocuparlo de manera global en otra operación.

```
<>
let table = ``;
 
await viewData.forEach((category, indx) => {
      table +=    `

         <div >
       <li  key="${indx}" onclick="(console.log(${indx}))" class="list-group-item"  > 
       ${category.name}
       </li></div>
       `

    });
    evento.innerHTML = table;
      `<div class="category">
    <ul class="list-group"">${table}</ul>
    </div>
    `
</>
```

Comment: Puedes crear un array global e ir guardando los indx, pero no tiene mucho sentido porque estarías guardando indx secuenciales hasta el largo de viewData, lo cual no es necesario de hacer. Mejor explica que es lo que buscas con estos indx a ver si te podemos ayudar

Comment: quiero q cada vez que haga click en una categoria se cambie el id dinamico que tienen mi url para mostrar productos

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que tu estas ocupando es React, no javascript puro. De React no sé nada, pero yo modifiqué tu código de esta manera y me funciona

```
const getProduct = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get(
      `https://bsale-erickseis.vercel.app/api/v1/products/` // ${i} valor dinamico?
    );
```

Esto de arriba se cambia por lo de abajo

```
window.getProduct = async (id=null) => {
  try {
    const result = await axios.get(
      `https://bsale-erickseis.vercel.app/api/v1/products/` + (id??"") // ${i} valor dinamico?

//etc...
    );
```

Lo primero es que la función getproduct se la asigné a window (no sé porque rayos no funciona como lo tenías tú, debe ser cosas de React)
Luego esta función acepta un parámetro opcional, que si no se coloca es null, el cual se concatena a la url (siempre que no sea null) y si es null muestra todos los productos

Luego en la función getCategory, donde tienes

```
    await viewData.forEach((category, indx) => {
      table += `
    <div >
    <li id="lo"  key="${indx}"  class="list-group-item"  >
```

Se cambia por:

```
    await viewData.forEach((category, indx) => {
      table += `
    <div >
    <li id="lo"  key="${indx}" onclick="window.getProduct(${indx})"  class="list-group-item"  >
```

Donde solo le agregue el evento onclick, el cual supongo que react tiene una forma mejor de colocar. Este evento vuelve a llamar a la función getProduct indicando la categoría.

Espero te sirva de algo

Comment: muchas gracias solucionaste mi dolor de cabeza :) eres el mejor